# Tasks getting duplicated when using multiple celery workers with same queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, multiprocessing, celery

I'm using celery to run tasks that are small and big in nature.

Setup:

- I'm using separate queues to handle small, medium, and large tasks independently.
- There are different celery workers catering to each of the different queues.
- Celery 5.2.7, Python 3.8.10
- Using Redis as the broker.
- Late ack set to True
- Prefetch count set to 1
- Visibility timeout set to max.
- Celery worker started with: `celery -A celeryapp worker --concurrency=1 -Ofair -l INFO -E -Q bigtask-queue -n big@%h`

I'm facing an issue where the tasks are getting duplicated across multiple workers of the same type. I'm auto-scaling based on the load on the CPU.

For e.g, when I have 4 tasks with a maximum of 4 workers, each of those 4 tasks is being queued up for execution on each of the 4 workers. I.e, each task is getting executed 4 times, once on each machine sequentially.

What I want is for them to execute just once. If one worker has picked up 1 task from the queue, the same shouldn't be picked by another worker. A new task should be picked only once the new node is up.

I have played with existing answers where setting visibility timeout to the maximum value, setting prefetch task to 1 along with late ack set to True. Nothing has helped.

What am I missing?

Does celery not recognize that the same task has already been picked up by the other worker?

Will using a flag on Redis for each task status work? Will there not be a race condition if multiple workers are already running?

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: How long does the task run and whats the visibility timeout?
here is the celery definition of the acknowledge 
acknowledged
Workers acknowledge messages to signify that a message has been handled. Failing to acknowledge a message will cause the message to be redelivered. Exactly when a transaction is considered a failure varies by transport. In AMQP the transaction fails when the connection/channel is closed (or lost), but in Redis/SQS the transaction times out after a configurable amount of time (the visibility_timeout).
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/glossary.html#term-acknowledged

Comment: Task runs for about 2-3 hours. Visibility timeout is set to 8 hours with late ack set to True. @Phteven

Comment: you can try the solo option we use it and dont have that issue: 
--without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat -Ofair -P solo

Comment: @Phteven We'd also tried with solo, no luck. Not hopeful about using those additional options as they aren't pertaining to what we're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have celery beat worker running?
something like this:

```
celery -A run.celery worker --loglevel=info --autoscale=5,2 -n app@beatworker --beat
```

We had the same problem, but now I don't remember how was it resolved. Try adding this separate worker with `--beat` option. there should be only one `--beat` running

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No, we don't use celery beat. These aren't tasks that need to run periodically, They're called upon on demand. @ashutosh